# Xcode UITest trying to read UITableviewcell Right Detail value

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I am trying to add UITest to my application, the computed results are displayed in a Table View (Style: Right Detail).  I have been able to read the 'Static Text' that is shown on the left side of the cell (the first line below), but I have not been able to determine how to read the 'Right Detail'; the second line shows where I want to test the Right Detail value (2 Points in this example).

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.staticTexts["Best of Breed"].exists)
//2 Points
```

Any help would be appreciated.

----- Update 28-Jul-2016 -----

I have found a method to specify when cell of the table the text should be in and I have verified that the '2 Points' does exist in the cell

The more specific XCTAssert

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.element.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["Best of Breed Best of Winners Winners Dog"].exists)
XCTAssert(app.tables.element.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["2 Points"].exists)
```

print app.tables.element.cells.element(boundBy: 0).debugDescription

```
(String) $R2 = "Attributes: Cell 0x600000364bc0: traits: 8589934593, {{16.0, 95.0}, {343.0, 78.0}}
Element subtree:
 →Cell 0x600000364bc0: traits: 8589934593, {{16.0, 95.0}, {343.0, 78.0}}
    StaticText 0x6000003651c0: traits: 8589934656, {{31.0, 105.0}, {115.0, 57.5}},
        label: \'Best of Breed Best of Winners Winners Bitch\'
    StaticText 0x600000365100: traits: 8589934656, {{265.5, 105.0}, {58.5, 19.5}},
        label: \'2 Points\'
    Path to element:
    →Application 0x6000003642c0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: \'Best of Breed\'
    ↳Window 0x600000364500: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    ↳Other 0x6000003645c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    ↳Other 0x600000364380: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0"...
```

Comment: can you give those elements(labels may be) accessibility labels? if yes, try to access those elements about the accessibility labels.

Comment: I'll do some research on that... Thanx

Answer (score 0):

These worked

```
XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["Best of Breed"].exists)
XCTAssert(app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["2 Points"].exists)
```